# Comparing items in an array while adding and deleting matches simultaneously

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, compare

I have this message board, for sale, wanted, type of program below. Ive finally figured out how to read everything in, but need advice on how to compare items. As I read in the file, want to check the array to see if an item that is wanted(true) and mathces the name of an item already in the array and is for sale. If a match is found don't add that item, and delete the wanted item from the array, and shift.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>


using namespace std;

struct messageBoard {
string item;
bool forSale;
int price;

};


int main(){
    messageBoard board;
    const int arrayLength = 100;
    std::list<messageBoard> arr;
    int index = 0;
    string filename;
    ifstream words;
    cout<<"Please enter the filename:";
    cin>>filename;
    words.open(filename);
    if (words.fail()) {
         cout << "file not found or something" << endl;
    }else {
         string word;;
        while (getline(words, word)) {
            int wordIndex = 0;
            stringstream ss;
            ss << word;
            while (getline(ss, word, ',')){
                 if (wordIndex==0){
                     board.item = word;
                    }
                 else if (wordIndex==1&&word==" for sale"){
                     board.forSale = false;
                     }
                 else if (wordIndex==1&&word==" wanted"){
                    board.forSale = true;
                    }
                 else if (wordIndex==2){
                    board.price = atoi(word.c_str());
                    }
                  wordIndex++;


            }
            index ++;
            arr.push_back(board);


        }
    }
    words.close();
    for(std::list<messageBoard>::iterator it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end();    it++) {
        std::cout << "item: " << (it)->item << " bool: " << (it)->forSale    <<"Price: "<<(it)->price << std::endl;
```

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write the code for you, but I'll tell you how I'd approach the problem.

First, I'd redefine `arr` as

```
std::list<MessageBoard> arr;
```

To add elements to the list, use `list::push_back`.

> if an item that is wanted(true) and mathces the name of an item already in the array

Write a `bool` function that returns true if those conditions are met, else false.

Scan the list with `std::find` or `std::find_if`, using your function.  If the search succeeds, the function returns an iterator pointing to the wanted item.

> delete the wanted item

Use `list::erase` on the iterator.  If you mess up, the result of deleting an invalid iterator is undefined, but likely your runtime library will let you know, loudly.

> and shift

No need.  The list length takes care of itself.

You might also consider `std::set` for efficient searches, or `std::map<MessageBoard, int>` to keep a count of identical elements.

By using the standard library containers, you elevate your logic from dealing with array elements by location, and move it closer to the problem of matching messages.  You'll also write fewer loops.

If I may suggest, I'd call `arr` something like `board` or `messages`.  Use the name to convey meaning not known to the compiler.  Also, atoi is a bit out of place here.  Since you're already in `stringstream` territory, you might as well extract the price that way.

```
stringstream sw(word);
sw >> arr[index].price;
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I can use as a guideline to move forward, much appreciated.

Comment: I've implemented the list like you suggested and it works great. What parameters would be needed for the Bool function you spoke of. Would I compare board and arr? @James K. Lowden